# Automatic silent update for corporative app

Tags: android

I have a private application for almost 20 customers.

We always need to update the application manually via team viewer.

I researched this, but I did not find a good solution or suggestion yet.

For example: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/DpGBZI9QrgQ

For example: https://blog.vivekpanyam.com/evolve-seamlessly-deploy-android-apps-to-users/

Do you  have any suggestions for an application to auto update itself.

**Note: I know Google play store politic, I am not using Google Play Store.**

Thanks for suggestions or solutions.

Comment: Why didn't the suggestions or solutions in your examples work for you?

Comment: first is only a suggestion. Second is really to much complex. Also i am not sure %100 for it is working all time.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to have a place at your server where versions can be downloaded from.
2. You need to have a place, maybe a database where you store your version releases.
3. Whenever you release a new version, you should store your new version at a place where it can be downloaded from and you need to make sure that you store somehow that you have a new version.
4. You need an installer which will extract the newest version of your application and installs it instead of the old version. This should be automatically placed at users.
5. Your application needs to check periodically by requesting the server whether there is a new version. If so, then the installer should be executed, which will download the new version, uninstall the old version and install the new version.

Comment: i think you only skip my "real" issue. 
For example all step which you write is done. So how i can auto install new apk ? This the point which i need.

Comment: @hyenican since you do not have support for that in your current version you will need to do that manually, in the way you have described in your question for one last time, to make sure that both the installer and the version of the application which runs it is there. Since your current version does not support it, you have no other options.